# Count cells with specific color and text

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to get this function to work properly.
I've tried and failed to add another variable.

I want to countif both the color and text match specific variables in a range.

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long

    xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex

    For Each datax In range_data
        If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor Then
            CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
        End If
    Next datax
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this. I assume the text you want to match is in cell with the color criteria. You may adapt it easily :

```
Function CountCcolor(range_data As Range, criteria As Range) As Long
    Dim datax As Range
    Dim xcolor As Long
    Dim xtext as String

xcolor = criteria.Interior.ColorIndex
xtext = criteria.value2

For Each datax In range_data
    If datax.Interior.ColorIndex = xcolor and datax.value2 = xtext Then
        CountCcolor = CountCcolor + 1
    End If
Next datax
End Function
```

Comment: I swear I tried his... its almost an exact match.  I had to look 2x as I thought I copied the wrong code.  Let me hop on my network quick and try it.  Thank you.

Comment: I will have to toy around with the code some more.  I tried to hard code the "text" too.  I am referring to a different workbook.  That may be causing an issue.  As an aside, the color and text do not need to be referenced in the same cell.

Comment: If you want more help, please give some more details on what fails.
If the code with only color index works, this one must work, unless the text in the cell datax is not the same than the text in the criteria range...

Comment: Or you have some text comparison problems (check your compare option ie: vbBinaryCompare / vbTextCompare / vbDataBaseCOmpare)

Sorry for the double answer, I had some difficulties with the return carriage and fire my message too early. The time I modify it it was too late to post the change...

Comment: Thanks again for your help Somedude.  I am finding this data to be more problematic than I originally thought.  I am typing this from my phone.  I will get back to the data tonight.  I should be very clear.  I haven't programmed in over 12 years and I was never the greatest at it.  I know enough to have a conversation but the how details take effort.  I am more comfortable with SQL and I will spearhead my company's effort to move to a PostgreSQL DB.  Yes, the update you provided works within a sheet.  I had written something similar, but I think the issues are related to the following.

Comment: I am populating a scorecard using a read only macro, enabled file on a different local file share location.  The worksheet I am running the function on has 3 rows of header material (wasted space).  The column I need to pull the data from is both color coordinated using a conditional format, and the text is populated using a drop down menu.  The refernc3d file utilizes more than one datasource and has 10 macros running on it. I started this solution as a way to start automating reports so I could free up my  team's time to focus on higher business value than navigating the Excel maze.

Comment: Hmmm. If it works within a sheet, you have to search why it doesn't in you case. Is you're call to CountCColor properly addressed . I mean, are the sheets containing range_data and criteria correctly  referenced ?

Comment: This is how I am using the reference to enter my variables.  `=CountCcolor('[List.xlsm]Inventory List'!$H:$H,'[List.xlsm]Inventory List'!$H$83)`

Comment: I've no more idea... Are you sure you use '.Value2' property and not '.Value' or something else ? You need to trace with the debugger what's your UDF sees when it compares text. The funny thing is that you're criteria will be counted in the total...

Comment: I will debug and see what the results are.  I am using Value2.  I've noticed a double count when selecting the column versus a specific range within the column.  Thanks for continuing to stick with me on this.